# XAML Window AllowsTransparency=True and ComboBox.IsEditable=True causes display error in WinXP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a WPF window, in which I have set the WindowStyle=None, AllowsTransparency=true. I have an editable combobox and a textbox which background is red in the window. When I run the application in Windows XP, textbox and combobox don't display correctly:

1. TextBox's background changes to transparent
2. TextBox's text disappear
3. ComboBox's border disappear

But I set Combobox.Editable=False or run this application in Win7, there is no problem. Why?
Please help me, thank you!

My environment:
WinXP SP3 + .Net Framework 4.0

Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="aaa" Height="30" Background="Red"></TextBox>
        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Height="30">
            <ComboBoxItem>aaa</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>bbb</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>ccc</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: is there any exception or error message? or application simply crash?

Comment: There is no exception, no error message, and application is not crash.  Just TextBox and ComboBox display not correctly.

Comment: what do you actually mean by display not correctly? maybe you can post some pictures for correct & incorrect display. I do not have WinXP here so I can't try on my own, but maybe I can hep you identify the cause and resolution.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to post image... can you access this image  link:http://d.pcs.baidu.com/thumbnail/f98c4e0bbd44c4ac46345f81f7dbd87e?fid=4063491355-250528-19671933281835&time=1405400400&sign=FDTAER-DCb740ccc5511e5e8fedcff06b081203-32hlzY4pNL4mA62qT7%2BartqGyjs%3D&rt=sh&expires=2h&r=475239497&sharesign=unknown&size=c710_u500&quality=100

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion in comments and looking at the posted image, seems like everything went transparent

you may perhaps as a workaround set a `Background` to `StackPanel`, this may apply a background to the controls within so they do not appear transparent.

eg

```
<StackPanel Background="White">
    <TextBox Text="aaa"
             Height="30"
             Background="Red"></TextBox>
    <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
              Height="30">
        <ComboBoxItem>aaa</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>bbb</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>ccc</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I didn't try this workaround as I do not have a `WinXP` machine. you may give it a try and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried it, but no effect. TextBox still go transparent.

Comment: Let's see if I can find a win xp machine, till then you may try figure out some windows API to set the style of the textbox window.

Comment: @LiXiang I think you've hit a bug mentioned here [Overlapping layered windows are not displayed in the correct order in Windows Server 2003 or in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943326). try this hotfix and see if that fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that this hotfix is contained in SP3. And I have installed SP3, but it doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: I think you may probably use `Clip` instead of `AllowsTransparency` in WinXP.